# Not detecting my android device despite my laptop did

Tags: android, usb, adb

I have been using android studio for the past 5 months and everything was fine. Suddenly, yesterday when i tried to debug my app android studio gave me the error of 'adb.exe start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary.

In an attempt to solve this, I

1. Killed adb.exe via task manager, restarted android studio and got the error
2. Opened command window,navigated to platform tools, adb kill-server and adb start-server, restarted android studio and still got error

Then,

1. I downloaded the latest platform-tools of version 28 something from the documentation.
2. Updated SDK tools from SDK managet to version 28.0.3
3. Updated Android emulator to a version of 28
4. Tried to debug my app, got no 'adb.exe start-server failed' error but my device is not being detected by the android adb despite it is detected by my laptop
5. Then i started again the command window, restarted the adb server, then i checked the connected devices on the adb by typing 'adb devices' but no devices was shown in the list.( maybe the problem is something here)
6. I toggled among the usb options on my phone, still my device is not detected on android.

Can somebody help me on this please?

Note: My android device is on debugging mode and this is the same device i have been using since 5 months on android studio.

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)

Answer (score 0):

**Install and configure your Android device:**

1. [Install the USB driver for your Android device.](https://www.embarcadero.com/starthere/xe5/mobdevsetup/android/en/installing_the_android_development_tools.html)
2. [Enable USB debugging on your Android device.](https://www.embarcadero.com/starthere/xe5/mobdevsetup/android/en/enabling_usb_debugging_on_an_android_device.html)
3. If necessary, [install the Android development tools (JDK/SDK/NDK)](https://www.embarcadero.com/starthere/xe5/mobdevsetup/android/en/adding_an_android_sdk.html).

These libraries are installed by default by the RAD Studio installer.

1. Add your Android SDK to the RAD Studio SDK Manager.
2. Connect your Android device to your development system using the USB
   cable provided with your device.
3. At the AutoPlay prompt, select Open device to view files.
4. In the Control Panel, search for and select "update device drivers".

**In the system Device Manager:**

5. Your Android device should be listed under Portable Devices. Locate
   and right-click your Android device, and select Update Software
   Driver.
6. Browse to the \extras folder in your installed  directory, and
   select the folder that matches your Android device. Then click OK.

For example, select google for the Nexus 7 or Nexus 10 tablet.
If you do not find a folder for your Android device, see Installing the [USB Driver for Your Android Device.](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Installing_the_USB_Driver_for_Your_Android_Device)

1. Verify that your Android device is now:

Listed in Windows Explorer, below the system disk drives, along with your mapped network drives.
Displayed in the Target node in the [Project Manager](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Project_Manager).

Comment: When You connect just check you changed to MTP